# Fanelli face detection - PCL code vs. author's implementation

Tags: c++, face-recognition, head, point-cloud-library

I am currently working with ASUS Xtion on the extraction of the face ROI in a depth+color stream. 
At the moment, I am manually grabbing the frames with OpenNI2 instead of using the PCL wrappers.

After grabbing the depth map I am generating the point cloud in a cv::Mat and a pcl::PointCloud format, respectively, to run Fanelli's decision forest method twice, once with the implementation which Fanelli provides himself (http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gfanelli/head_pose/head_forest.html) and once with the PCL version of that method.

Fanelli's code performs "normal", i.e. regarding execusion time and detection rate. However, when I'm feeding my pcl::PointClouds to the PCL forest I hardly get detected heads and the execusion times are quite slow.

Has anyone else already been doing a comparison between those two implementations (of the same method!)? 
I am trying to figure out the differences between them, besides data representation and the existing forest that come with each method respectively (however, the forests were trained on the same DB!).

---

Basically, I am doing it like this:

```
<grab frames with OpenNI2 library>
<call processNewFrame method of a frame processing class>
```

withing that processNewFrame method:

```
<convert float[] depthmap into cv::Mat and pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pointcloud>
CRForestEstimator->estimate(..., cv::Mat pointcloud, ...)
pcl::RFFaceDetectorTrainer->setInputCloud(PointXYZ version of pointcloud)
pcl::RFFaceDetectorTrainer->detectFaces()
```

That frame processing class initializes the CRForestEstimator (class has pointer as member) as well as the pcl::RFFaceDetectorTrainer (class has "normal" member variable) in its constructor according to provided sample code.

Comment: Probably you would get better help in the PCL-users list.

Comment: Thank you for your hint but [I already posted my issue there](http://www.pcl-users.org/Fanelli-face-detection-PCL-code-vs-author-s-implementation-td4038521.html). However, I got no reply yet.